# shiny runs undesirable scripts on R folder

Tags: r, shiny

This issue shook me. Lets a minimal reproducible example:

1. On RStudio, create a New Project... Choose Shiny Web App. Check that sample app runs well.
2. Create inside the standard *R* folder, to put all your *.R scripts.
3. Create a dummy script inside the R folder that fails, but you do not want run yet. For example

   ```
   str(do_not_exist)      ## foo.R
   ```

4.Run the App again. Now, the App fails

```
> runApp()
Error in str(do_not_exist) : objeto 'do_not_exist' no encontrado
```

Why Shiny runs undesirable scripts? They are OUT of the root directory.
I am not finding ways to save scripts that are not functions within the project.

This is my R Session

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Argentina.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Argentina.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Argentina.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Argentina.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tidyr_1.1.3         dplyr_1.0.5         openxlsx_4.2.3.9000 shiny_1.6.0        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        magrittr_2.0.1    tidyselect_1.1.0  xtable_1.8-4     
 [5] R6_2.5.0          rlang_0.4.10      fastmap_1.1.0     fansi_0.4.2      
 [9] tools_4.0.5       utf8_1.2.1        DBI_1.1.1         withr_2.4.2      
[13] htmltools_0.5.1.1 ellipsis_0.3.1    assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.27    
[17] tibble_3.1.1      lifecycle_1.0.0   crayon_1.4.1      zip_2.1.1        
[21] purrr_0.3.4       later_1.1.0.1     vctrs_0.3.7       promises_1.2.0.1 
[25] glue_1.4.2        mime_0.10         stringi_1.5.3     compiler_4.0.5   
[29] pillar_1.6.0      generics_0.1.0    httpuv_1.5.5      pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/app-formats.html). One option is `options(shiny.autoload.r = FALSE)`.